# arranging content on boostrap 4 with side image

Tags: html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I want to get this style:[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llugq.png)

I've used col-md-6, and float-left for the image, and achieved somehow the effect, but if there is more text the text will go under the image and I don't want that, I want image to remain top left and the text should not go under.

The second problem is on mobile view, I want to look like this (check the second image)
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXQfT.png)

I think there should be some tricks with flexbox? 
I'm using this for testimonials, if you have some other options please share :)

LE:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 clearfix">
<img style="width: 130px; height: 130px; margin-right: 20px;" src="profile.png" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="...">
<h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
<p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved. Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. 
c!</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 clearfix">
<img style="width: 130px; height: 130px; margin-right: 20px;" src="profile.png" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="...">
<h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
<p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved. Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. 
c!</p> 
    </div>

    </div>
    <Br> <br> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 clearfix">
<img style="width: 130px; height: 130px; margin-right: 20px;" src="profile.png" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="...">
<h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
<p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved. Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. 
c!</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 clearfix">
<img style="width: 130px; height: 130px; margin-right: 20px;" src="profile.png" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="...">
<h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
<p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved. Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. 
c!</p> 
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: i;ve edited the post

Answer (score 1):

You're not far from it. You can collect the columns in a single row and apply a flex on the column. Here is something to start with.

```css
@media(min-width:767px) {
  .text-center {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }
  .flex>div {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-6 flex clearfix">
        <img style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="...">
        <div>
          <h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
          <p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved.
            Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. c!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 flex clearfix">
        <img style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="...">
        <div>
          <h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
          <p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved.
            Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. c!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-6 flex clearfix">
        <img style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="..." />
        <div>
          <h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
          <p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved.
            Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. c!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 flex clearfix">
        <img style="width: 130px; height: 130px;" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="img-testimonial float-left" alt="..." />
        <div>
          <h5><strong> H3 Headline</strong></h5>
          <p style="font-size: 1rem; color: #444;"> Alteration literature to or an sympathize mr imprudence. Of is ferrars subject as enjoyed or tedious cottage. Procuring as in resembled by in agreeable. Next long no gave mr eyes. Admiration advantages no he celebrated so pianoforte unreserved.
            Not its herself forming charmed amiable. Him why feebly expect future now. c!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but for Bootstrap 4..https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/